# reload api data on next/prev buttons in fullcalendar v4

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

i am trying to fetch  the json data from API on next/prev buttons with following code, but it is not working on 2nd time we press the button
my code is as follow

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        $scope.calendarObj = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid','interactionPlugin' ],
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next, today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
            },
            // defaultDate: '2020-06-18', if null, it will fetch current day.
            nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00',
            slotDuration: '00:15:00',
            defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
            lazyFetching : false,
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            selectable: true,
            selectMirror: true,
            select: function(arg) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    $scope.calendarObj.addEvent({
                        title: title,
                        start: arg.start,
                        end: arg.end,
                        allDay: arg.allDay
                    })
                }
                $scope.calendarObj.unselect()
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
                fetchEventsByDate(start.start,start.end) //  used to call json api and fetch the data
            },
            dateClick: onEmptySlotClick,
        });
        $scope.calendarObj.render();
```

In fetchEventsByDate method, i called the following method to display the data in calendar.

```
$scope.refresh_events = function () {
    var eventSources = $scope.calendarObj.getEventSources();
    var len = eventSources.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(eventSources[i])
        eventSources[i].remove();
    }
    $scope.calendarObj.addEventSource( $scope.events );
    $scope.calendarObj.render();
};
```

but it is not working. can please anyone guide me, where i am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your overall approach here:

1. `events: function(start, end, callback)` is incorrect. This was the function signature in fullCalendar 3. In fullcalendar 4 it's `function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback )`. This is very clear from the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-function). If you are copying examples from elsewhere please make sure they apply to the correct version.
2. The idea with the events-as-a-function is to use the supplied callback to return the events to fullCalendar. It shouldn't be used to add and remove new event sources. This is very inefficient compared to simply returning the event data to fullCalendar directly. Your fetchEventsByDate method should return the newly fetched array of event data, so it can be used to supply the callback.

Your events function would then look like this:

```
events: function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback ) {
  successCallback(fetchEventsByDate(fetchInfo.start,fetchInfo.end)); //  used to call json api and fetch the data
}
```

P.S. if the data is fetched from an API asynchronously, then it might be necessary for `fetchEventsByDate` to return a Promise - but that's fine because fullCalendar can use that, as long as the promise returns the event data array when it resolves. Something like this:

```
events: function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback ) {
  var promise = fetchEventsByDate(fetchInfo.start,fetchInfo.end); //  used to call json api and fetch the data
  return promise;
}
```

In either case your whole `$scope.refresh_events` function would then be redundant and could be removed.

P.S. there may of course be other bugs which are not apparent from the code shown, but unfortunately in your question you simply described the functionality as "not working", a description which doesn't provide any useful information at all. So in the absence of any accurate description of the current behaviour of the code which might provide clues as to the root cause of specific issues, I've assumed that the changes above are all that's necessary to make it do what's expected.

Comment: i have another issue,  when events are fetched, then i want to set the minTime and maxTime 
 for that specific week / day, but setting those options causes events to be fetched again causing infinite loop.

Comment: You can't do that, it isn't how the calendar is intended to be used. To be honest I think it would be confusing for users anyway, if you keep shrinking and expanding the grid. They will just get used to, say, 1pm being at a certain place in the grid and in their eyeline, and then you'd change it to further up or down. I don't think it's user-friendly. Why did you want to change it?

Comment: user can switch to other user with dropdown and each user has its own starting/ending timings, hence i need to configure it in this way.

Comment: Rather than changing the view, I suggest you set business hours for each user, to show their general available times. You can update these via the settings.

Comment: when i tried to set business hour dynamically, then it re-fetched the events again.



var userBusinessHours = {
                                businessHours: {
  // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
  daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Thursday

  startTime: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
  endTime: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
}
                            }
                            calendar.setOption('businessHours', userBusinessHours);

Comment: Hm. Seems like doing that must also re-render the whole view then. Maybe you'd be better to show the unavailable times for each user using [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/background-events) - you can include this is the user's event feed, so it wouldn't require you to mess with the view itself.